# Noting I do removes "index.php" from CodeIgniter 4 url

Tags: routes, vagrant, codeigniter-4

I'm thinking it might be some issue with vagrant?  But I've tried for days now every tutorial online to remove the index.php from codigniter 4 but nothing has worked

My apache config file:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

my .htaccess file (I've tried removing/adding all the stuff on tutorials for here with nothing? Everthing says if I have rewriteRule (.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] it should work.  It does not)

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

My htaccess and index.php file have been pulled out of the public folder and in main directory

my App.php file relevent code:

```
  public $baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * Index File
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
     * something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
     * variable so that it is blank.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $indexPage = '';

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * URI PROTOCOL
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *
     * This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
     * URI string.  The default setting of 'REQUEST_URI' works for most servers.
     * If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
     *
     * 'REQUEST_URI'    Uses $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
     * 'QUERY_STRING'   Uses $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
     * 'PATH_INFO'      Uses $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
     *
     * WARNING: If you set this to 'PATH_INFO', URIs will always be URL-decoded!
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $uriProtocol = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

And lastly in the index.php file I changed "require FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php'" to "require FCPATH . '/app/config/Pathos.php'"

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]` and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` in the **same** `.htaccess` file? Try following [`CodeIgniter4/public/.htaccess`](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/f9d09b91453173d666dcfc31a2fdaee34b74c351/public/.htaccess#L32)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is setting this variable

```
public $indexPage = '';
```

You don't need to change anything in other files. I think the issue is mod_rewrite module is not enabled in your server. Try running following commands. First one for enabling mod_rewrite. Then restart apache server.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks, yes the a2enmod rewrite was the issue.